# Modify Logic App Connections in Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to modify the connections of my Azure Logic Apps to support automated deployments from Dev to Test to Prod. Part of this is to update the Connection names and IDs from `-d-` to `-t-` to `-p-`.

I can't find a way to do this.

```
# Get Logic App
$LogicApp = Get-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName $RG_Name -Name $LA_Name

#Display Connections
$LogicApp.Parameters.'$connections'.Value
```

The value I want to modify is in the `Parent` property but I don't really understand the structure of the object. If I go expand `$LogicApp.Parameters.'$connections'.Value | select -ExpandProperty Parent` it starts recursing through the values to a seemingly unlimited depth. I've tried every kind of `Replace` but it always converts the object from `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Logic.Models.Resource.Workflow.Parameters` to `JSON`. It must remain as an `Object` otherwise it wipes out my connections when I `Set` back to the Logic app.

Anyone know how to accomplish a replace on this object?

Example is the following screen shot. I have anonymised it except for the `-d-` strings I'm trying to replace.
[image: Screeshot]

Comment: Could you provide json before and after updating that you want?

Comment: Added a bit of extra details and a screenshot of my output. It must remain as an `Object` otherwise it wipes out my connections when I Set back to the Logic app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if I understand you correctly, you want to modify the `connectionName` and `connectionId` of the connections. Which also can be seen in the portal -> logic app -> `Logic app code view` like below.

[image]

I notice you have four connections in your screenshot. In my sample, there just two connections i.e. `Root : {azureblob, sql}`.

Try the commands as below, it works fine on my side. In your own case, add the other lines for the connections like the sample.

```
$logicapp = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -ResourceType Microsoft.Logic/workflows -ResourceName "<logic app name>"

$logicapp.Properties.parameters.'$connections'.value.azureblob.connectionId = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob"
$logicapp.Properties.parameters.'$connections'.value.azureblob.connectionName = "azureblob"

$logicapp.Properties.parameters.'$connections'.value.sql.connectionId = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql"
$logicapp.Properties.parameters.'$connections'.value.sql.connectionName = "sql"

$logicapp | Set-AzResource -Force
```

After running the script, you could use your original commands to check the result.

```
$LogicApp = Get-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Name <logic app name>
$LogicApp.Parameters.'$connections'.Value
```

Comment: That's fantastic. Thank you!